# Summing a calculated field in the same query can it be done?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

```
PARAMETERS [First Date] DateTime, [Second Date] DateTime, [Shift] Text ( 255 );
SELECT
    Main.[Mth/day],
    Main.Shift,
    ([Run Hrs]*[Actual Lbs/hr]) AS [Gross Production - LBS],
    [Scrap Lbs 1]+[Scrap Lbs 2]+[Scrap Lbs 3] AS [Scrap Produced - LBS],
    [Run Hrs]*[Actual Lbs/hr]-([Scrap Lbs 1]+[Scrap Lbs 2]+[Scrap Lbs 3]) AS [Net Production],
    [Run Hrs]*[Actual Lbs/hr]*0.035 AS [Scrap Target],
    [Run Hrs]*[Std lbs/hr]-([Run Hrs]*[Actual Lbs/hr])*0.035 AS [Target Net Production],
    [Run Hrs]*[Std lbs/hr] AS [Target Gross Production],
    (([Run Hrs]*[Std Lbs/hr])/([Run Hrs]*[Actual Lbs/hr]*0.035)) AS [Target Scrap Rate]
FROM Main
WHERE
    (((Main.[Mth/day]) Between [First Date] And [Second Date]
    And [Shift]=Main.Shift
    And [Std lbs/hr]>0));
```

I need to also sum each calculated field so they can also retrieve monthly summaries and the like. Can i do this in the same query or am I best to make another query based off of this one's results?

Comment: I don't think you should use Sum() that way.  It's a SQL aggregate function which is applied to the full result set, or to subsets of rows when you're using a GROUP BY expression.  Does the db engine run that query without complaint?  If so, does it give you what you want as `[Gross Production - LBS]`?

Comment: @HansUp Thanks very much for the fast reply good sir, I have the query running without any sum() operator - It does all the correct calculations to display the data we need. What I want to also include is a sum of each calculated field. I'm going to use this data to feed a report that has daily data as well as a monthly summary. So when it runs it asks me for date1, date2, then shift a, b, c, or d I need to be able to sum the data in the parameter range so i can place it at the bottom of the report

Comment: I'm not sure you need a separate query for the sums, Matthew.  Base the report on the detail data only.  Then add text boxes to the report footer whose control sources are the sums of the relevant Detail section controls.  Does that make sense?  Hope so, cause I can't think how to explain it better.  :-(  And I also hope I didn't totally misinterpret what you're asking for.

Comment: @HansUp I didn't know you could do that, I'm a web dev guy more than anything I was going to make this into a web based tool initially so I could add it to my portfolio (genericized version without real data) but they denied my request to use MySql and told me MS Access or nothing. I was thinking the report design section was more of a front end aspect. Where exactly would I place my Sum() expression directly in a text box on the form or is their a special little home for it? I've only been using Access for one week if you can believe it hahaha.

Comment: I edited your question to remove `Sum()` from the query ... which is what I think you're saying you actually have.  Change it back if I'm wrong.

Comment: "a text box on the form"  I thought we were talking about a report, not a form.

Comment: ophe my bad it's most certainly a report, typo

Comment: @Tom H. suggested something better than I had in mind. I was just going to manually add a text box to the footer, then set its control source property to =Sum([DetailSectionControlName])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really something that should be handled in the front-end or report writer, not through SQL.

In MS Access 2007 the following should work:

1. Open your report in layout view
2. Click on one of the cells in the column that you want to total
3. On the **Format** tab click on **Totals** and select **Sum**

A cell should be added to the report footer with your aggregate.

Comment: Aaaah this worked, Thanks so much to both @Tom H. and HansUp much much appreciated you guys rock! This is my first "db" contract and boy have a learned a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Start with a query which uses only fields and field expressions which don't use [SQL Aggregate Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177686%28office.12%29.aspx).  Then save that query and use it as the data source for another query where you do your summing and any other aggregate functions.

In other cases, you could take just the SQL from the first query and use it as a subquery in another query.  However, because of those square brackets required for the names, this one would be troublesome as a subquery.

In the future, you can make it easier on yourself by choosing object names which don't require bracketing.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, learned a bunch in a short amount of time!